# JavaScript get textContent excluding children

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries

First, I'm creating a library for JavaScript and I can not use jQuery. I'm trying to get the text content of an HTML element without the text contents of its children.

Both attributes innerText and textContent don't give me what needed, please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can solve using DOM API as childNodes and nodeType.

```
var elChildNode = document.querySelector("#hello").childNodes;
var sChildTextSum = "";

elChildNode.forEach(function(value){
    if(value.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) { 
        console.log("Current textNode value is : ", value.nodeValue.trim());
        sChildTextSum += value.nodeValue;
    }
}); 

console.log("All text value of firstChild : ", sChildTextSum);
```

I created a sample code as above.

https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/p7t9bdc3/

Comment: Please don't use Hungarian notation

Answer (score 6):

To get `Author's Name` from the following element, excluding `<span>...`:

```
<div class="details__instructor">
    Author's Name<span ng-show="job_title">, Entrepreneur</span>
</div>
```

use `childNodes[0]`. For example:

```
document.querySelector('div.details__instructor').childNodes[0].textContent
```

Comment: This will simply return the 1st child node, nothing else. So I am not wondering if this answer down-voted.
(Maybe you have mistakenly missed the exact logic to type here)

Comment: This is an entry point to the solution. One can test for any type, and even do so recursively.

Comment: This doesn't return a text value!
Should be voted down so more people don't get confused

Answer (score 3):

Using only JavaScript (you specified you cannot use jQuery), and given that you have provided and know the `id` for the parent element:

```
document.getElementById('parent_element_id').childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

You can also use `.trim()` to remove any trailing space characters left behind from the removal of any child element text:

```
document.getElementById('parent_element_id').childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
```

Comment: This should be at the top of this page. It's the most logical and straight to the point answer. Pls upvote so more people could access the right answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mydiv = getElementByID("id");
function Get_text(element) {
    var selected = element.cloneNode(true);
    var text;
    while (selected.firstChild) {
      if (selected.firstChild.nodeType == 3) text = selected.firstChild.nodeValue;
      selected.removeChild(selected.firstChild);
    }
    return text;
  }
Get_text(mydiv);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community

Comment: 3 is better expressed as `Node.TEXT_NODE`. What's the point of destroying these elements in the DOM? This doesn't add explanation or obvious benefit over [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36232386/6243352).

Answer (score 1):

I know many good solutions here exist, but none of them actually achieved what I needed (get the textContent of a **single** node, none of its children), so sharing this for future searchers.

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
    var el = html[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < el.children.length; j++) {
        var child = el.children[j],
            childTextContent = child.innerHTML;
        // Remove all children tags, leaving only the actual text of the node.
        childTextContent = childTextContent.replace(/\<.*\>.*\<\/.*\>/gmi, "");
        // Also remove <img /> type tags.
        childTextContent = childTextContent.replace(/\<.*\ \/\>/gmi, "");
        console.log(childTextContent);
        // Now you can do any type of text matching (regex) on the result.
    }
});
```