# Puppeteer - How to get innerText ignoring children

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I am looking to get the innerText of a h3 but I would like to ignore the nested span.

Example:

```
<h3>
    <span>NEW</span>
    Blog Article #69
</h3>
```

Here's my current code:

```
const title = await blogArticle.$eval(
    "h3",
    (el) => el.textContent
  );
```

It returns

```
NEWBlog Article #69
```

Also tried innerText with no success and I can't manage to delete the span from the DOM.

Comment: I'm not very sure on this but can you try ```const elm = await page.$(".h3");
const text = await page.evaluate(elm => elm.textContent, elm[0]);
console.log(text);```.

Comment: This isn't strictly a Puppeteer problem because you can (and should) solve it entirely in the browser code inside `$eval` as described in [JavaScript get textContent excluding children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231897/javascript-get-textcontent-excluding-children). The correct approach is to iterate the children and use `child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE` to find the text.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the H3 does not contain any more tags this will work

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <body>
    <h3>
    <span>NEW</span>
    Blog Article #69
    </h3>    
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);
  const title = await page.$eval(
    "h3",
    (el) => el.innerHTML
  );

  const span = await page.$eval(
    "h3 span",
    (el) => el.innerText
  );

  var h3WithoutSpan = title.replace(`<span>${span}</span>`, "" ).trim();
  console.log("-->" + h3WithoutSpan);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This returns `-->Blog Article`

This does the following

1. Gets the inner HTML of H3
2. Gets the text of the span (assume this can be other words than just NEW)
3. Removes `<span>NEW</span>` and then any white space